# UIWebView get user touch on tapping link

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I want to perform some action when the user clicks any link on `UIWebView`. I am doing this for making this work :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"request - %@", request.URL.absoluteString);
    [webView.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    if(isFirstTimeLoaded)
    {
        [self shoToolbar];
        [self updateButtons];
    }


    return YES;
}  

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{   
    isFirstTimeLoaded = YES;
}
```

This usually works fine. But it doesn't when `UIWebView`'s first load involves multiple redirection while loading the page. What I want is to fire this condition only when the user intentionally clicks on the link. Not on the url redirection of `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check navigationType

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {

        if (navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
            // It was a link
        } else {
           // It wasn't a link
        }


        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Stupid I was forgetting about navigationType. Thanks !!